# payment accepted email changes

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

Hello I want to change in email of the payment accepted in prestashop.

1. How can I add one new value in payment email and replace the
   reference to order id.
2. Where is the method of sending emails of payment statuses.
3. In which file I need to change .txt or .html file for viewing email.

Comment: Do you want to change senders email address on payment accepted status?

Answer (score 0):

Mail templates are in the "mails" directory of your prestashop installation.
There is a subdirectory for each locale (language).

You must edit both the html and txt version of the templates.
Also : themes can override mail templates by placing templates in their mails directory.